# Pipe angular-file-upload request with image to Azure in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I almost have this working. I use angular-file-upload (http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/) to upload a file to nodejs server and I pipe it through to Azure.

```js
router.post('/storeimg', function (req, res, next) {
    //create write stream for blob
    var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService();
    
    blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('images', function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            // Container exists and allows
            // anonymous read access to blob
            // content and metadata within this container

            var stream = blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(
                'images', 
                'test.png');
            
            //pipe req to Azure BLOB write stream
            req.pipe(stream);

            req.on('error', function (error) {
                //KO - handle piping errors
                console.log('error: ' + error);
            });
            req.once('end', function () {
                //OK
                console.log('all ok');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I have is that resulting file on Azure is prepended with the following

```
-----------------------------7df240321a0e9a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="010218_osn.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Which seems I also end up piping in the headers of the POST request. How do I avoid this? Is there a way to skip the headers?

**UPDATE: Solution**

```js
var Busboy = require('busboy');
```

```js
router.post('/storeimg', function (req, res, next) {
    //create write stream for blob
    var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService();
    
    blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('images', function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            // Container exists and allows
            // anonymous read access to blob
            // content and metadata within this container

            var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

            busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
                var stream = blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(
                    'images', 
                    filename);

                //pipe req to Azure BLOB write stream
                file.pipe(stream);
            });
            busboy.on('finish', function () {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
                res.end("That's all folks!");
            });

            req.pipe(busboy);

            req.on('error', function (error) {
                //KO - handle piping errors
                console.log('error: ' + error);
            });
            req.once('end', function () {
                //OK
                console.log('all ok');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you probably shouln't pipe the request directly, mabe you can try to make a multipart reader from your request before

Comment: Thanks, MayK, you're entirely correct, of course. Posting update with problem solved via Busboy.